# How to uninstall or upgrade Erlang/OTP?

Tags: erlang

How can I uninstall **Erlang/OTP** which I use `make install` to build from source earlier. The install is pretty simple by using `./configure;make;make install;`

The reason to uninstall is that I want to upgrade from **Erlang R15B01** to **Erlang R15B03**.

Now I have:

```
# erl --version
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an option --prefix=path of script configure, where path is a path to directory where you want to install an application. For instance:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/erlang-R15B01
```

Do not forget to add appropriate path to PATH environment variable.

If you didn't use this option during previous installation then the default path was used (/usr or /usr/local) and you can just install new version above old one the same way -

```
./configure && make && make install.
```

Answer (score 40):

How to uninstall Erlang on Ubuntu:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge erlang*
```

Uninstall Erlang on Fedora:

```
sudo yum remove erlang*
```

If you installed erlang from source using the default home directory, you would need to `rm -rf /usr/local/erlang/`.

Additional cleanup might me required if you had manually copied libraries or executable to other
folders, like */lib or */bin.

Comment: For **19.x** path is: `/usr/local/lib/erlang/`

Comment: Mine as in `/usr/lib/erlang/`

Comment: Erlang is an obfuscation language so as to protect the source c++ code from any prying eyes.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Erlang for development I would suggest looking into [kerl VM manager](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl). It allows you to have multiple VM "installed" with different configuration options and possibility  of switching between them.

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative to kerl, we can also use erln8 to have multiple Erlang environment.

https://erln8.github.io/erln8/