# Remove old built erlang from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, kerl

I used this script to install erlang.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bryanhunter/10380945/raw/b4edf4c6fd39c604392a96ce6ff21953ff941e51/build-erlang-17.0.sh

but later I found out https://github.com/yrashk/kerl. My question is how to remove old version of erlang in a clean way.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge erlang* See also [How to uninstall or upgrade Erlang/OTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396240/how-to-uninstall-or-upgrade-erlang-otp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there are just four folders affected by the installation:

**`bin` executables**:

```
/usr/local/bin/ct_run
/usr/local/bin/dialyzer
/usr/local/bin/epmd
/usr/local/bin/erl
/usr/local/bin/erl_call
/usr/local/bin/erlc
/usr/local/bin/escript
/usr/local/bin/run_erl
/usr/local/bin/snmpc
/usr/local/bin/to_erl
/usr/local/bin/typer
```

**configuration file and `epmd` starting script**:

```
/usr/local/etc/man.d/erlang.conf
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/epmd
```

**a lib folder containing Erlang libraries**:

```
/usr/local/lib/erlang/*
```

**and the documentation**:

```
/usr/local/share/doc/erlang/
```

They may be located slightly differently on your system, but you can always use something like `find . -type d -name erlang` to locate them.

That script you mentioned also installs some dependencies. You may use standard `apt-get` command to deinstall if needed, but they probably will be required by the Erlang installed by `kerl` anyway.